# How to show a Bitmap fit to the width of the screen?

Tags: android, bitmap

i have a bitmap, and i need to show it on my screen with fit horizontally all the diwth of the screen of my current phone (320 pixels).

i'm trying it but something is going wrong.

The problem is that the bitmap is not getting the width i want. It is getting two empty spaces on the left and on the right. It is because it is fitting the height of the screen, but i dont want that, i want to force the bitmap to have the width i want. Doesn't matter if a portion of the height of the bitmap is out of the screen.

i need to force the width when i am adding the image to the layout, i mean that the image must be keep the aspect ratio, but the image must be higher than the height of the screen, and the image must be shown incomplete if the heigh of the image is higher than the height of the screen. Now this is not happening, because the layout is forcing the width to respect the image and show all the height of the image in the height of the screen, then i think the problem is on the layout rules

im creating the bitmap with:

```
View view;
Bitmap aux = Util.loadImage( filename ); //image loaded but with his original width
Bitmap image = Util.scaleBitmap(aux, 320); //scaling to 320
((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap( resource.image );

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( 320 , h );
rlp.addRule( RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL );
rlp.addRule( RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP );

layout.addView( view , rlp );
```

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 4):

In XML file like the image view must have layout width equal to fill_parent as below and use scaleType attribute also.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

In Java file same thing will be achieved by using below code. i am talking only about scaleType not layout_width, layout_width must be fill_parent for using java code also.

```
setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

I hope you understand this.

Comment: it works more or less, but it is strething the height, and i dont want to strectch the height, i only want to stretch the width, is not possible?

Comment: if you are using fill_parent for both layout_width and layout_height it will stretch in both directions.

Comment: no, i'm using a fixed width and height for the layout, i'm not using fill parent

Comment: i tryed also with FILL_PARENT on the width and i have the same problem, stretching x and Y, but i need only to stretch the X

Comment: fitXY means whatever the width and height you are using, to that values it will stretch the given image.i think some thing you are doing wrong. Its working fine for me. Test it with simple code, you will understand this attribute.

Comment: Read the link I posted!  scaleType is the answer, but not FIT_XY, that will stretch the bitmap to fill both bounds.  Use scaleType.CENTER_INSIDE, or one of the other scaleTypes that preserves the ratio.

Comment: I tested using Android 2.2, CENTER_INSIDE is not stretching anything.

Comment: CENTER_INSIDE works just fine.  I use it all the time.  From the Android docs, in the link I sent:  Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).  Are you setting the source or the background image?

Comment: source only, for background no need to use any scale type, it will stretch automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use android:scaleType="fitXY" this tag .

Comment: how to do it programatically with java?

Comment: it works more or less, but it is strething the height, and i dont want to strectch the height, i only want to stretch the width, is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should never hard code the number of pixels unless you're using DIP (device independent pixels).  It might work on your phone, at 320 width, but what about another phone?  Or a tablet?

You should use ImageView.scaleType.  See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

CENTER_INSIDE is probably what you need.

Comment: how to do it programatically with java?

Answer (score 0):

Use **android:background** in XML file for ImageView, the image you are setting as background will stretch the entire screen width if **android:layout_width = "fill_parent"** for that ImageView. This is not image source, the background attribute.

In Java file same thing will be achieved by below code.

```
setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimagefile));
```

You can use my suggestions if you like it for temporarily. Once again i ma telling i am suggesting to use **background** attribute not **src** attribute of **ImageView**

I am also trying same effect for image view's source not to background. I hope it may help you.